# Issue un-extruding flat bottom of an object

Tags: extrude

I am extremely new to blender so sorry if there is an obvious solution here. Essentially I extruded the bottom of this object more than I like, so I'm trying to un-extrude it a bit. But when I un-extrude it, the edges seem to stay for some reason and not un-extrude as well. Is there a simple solution to this that I'm missing? [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "un-extrude"? Either you've before extruded twice, or you just need to grab back the extruded part (so don't extrude it again inside, just grab it)..

Comment: By un-extrude I mean remove the part I've extruded. I tried to do that by using the extruding tool again but pulling inward (like how I would remove parts in fuction 360).

Comment: Yes... if you want to lower the size of the extrusion, don't extrude again, just grab back the extrusion.

Comment: How do I grab it back? I try to do what you say but I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: Use the move tool to grab it to the size you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new *Extrude Manifold* tool.
It works exactly as you describe, without creating additional faces.

[image]

Comment: I don't have that command. How do I access that command?

Comment: @Jachym yes +1 but this tool may create ngons... so some limitations

Comment: @lemon You're right, it's good to keep that in mind :). I just dig the yellow handle :)).

Comment: It worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

You can grab back the extrusion:

[image]

Comment: Indeed once created, there is no need to extrude again, just move the vertices\edges\faces to the desired location.